# How to show progress bar before fragment loading when fragment view loading is part of asynctask?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have a fragment to show a calendar month view with specific images for each date decided by some logic in runtime. As the fragment loading takes some time, I want to show a progress bar. Since the progress bar itself is part of the fragment view, how can i show it before asynctask finishes. The fragment view is created as per the logic placed within asynctask.

Showing some code snippet for clarity.

```
public class CalendarMonthViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnCalculateMonthlyCompleted {

@BindView(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new CalculateMonthlyDataTask(this, progressBar).execute(); //asynctask that decides the view
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_monthview_fragment, container, false);

}

  private class CalculateMonthlyDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MonthlyDataResult> {

    private OnCalculateMonthlyCompleted listener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private CalculateMonthlyDataTask(OnCalculateMonthlyCompleted listener, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MonthlyDataResult monthlyDataResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(monthlyDataResult);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(monthlyDataResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected MonthlyDataResult doInBackground(Void... params) {

        panchangMonthlyController.calculateMonthlyCalendar();
        return panchangMonthlyController.getMonthlyDataResult();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that a way to solve this using ProgressDialog. I just show the progressDialog before the view is loaded in this case and cancel the progressDialog after the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you must showing progressbar in the activity class and cancel it when fragment loaded

Comment: Can you suggest some code showing how that can be done